# Using structs in C# for simple domain values

Tags: c#, .net, struct, dns

I am writing a financial application where the concept of 'Price' is used a lot. It's currently represented by the C# `decimal` type. I would like to make it more explicit and be able to change it to maybe `double` in the future, so I was thinking of creating a 'Price' struct that would basically act exactly the same as the decimal type (maybe add a bit of validation like must be greater than 0).

**What do you think are the pros and cons of doing this?**

Comment: perhaps it should be instead a member of a prototype/virtual class that is inherited by the item class, accessed with get/setters?

Comment: @Nona: Sorry, I don't get it. What exactly do you mean and what is that good for?

Comment: well I could be wrong, but it seems (to me) like a struct should be used to contain a set of values, not to just be a wrapper for a single piece of data. Because "price" is a single piece of data, and because price on its own is useless (price of what?), it should instead be a property of the larger class (price of Item). The g/setters will allow you to later put logic into their retrieval/alterations. Finally, I suggested a virtual class to allow you to have fundamentally different Item types but inherit their base characteristics, and forcing you to override what you know will change.

Comment: This sounds like a great time to apply the YAGNI principle. You Ain't Gonna Need It. I would not be designing my data types for the possibility that someday I might want to refactor them in the future. Premature generality is expensive, and you don't know what your needs are going to be in the future. What makes a program extensible in the future is not an excessive amount of abstraction to permit you to change implementation details,  but rather a clean, clear model of business domain concepts.  If you get the model right, you can extend the model to new scenarios in the future.

Comment: Next to the YAGNI principle (which it is : I would & maybe in one sentence)...  I'd like to say that doubles are not really the preffered data-type to use when it comes in storing monetary amounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a reason to change the data type for a quantity like this; however, you may decide to add other information such as the currency or the number of decimal places to keep track of in calculations, so using a struct at this point will save you a LOT of time down the road.

Answer (score 5):

**Please** don't use double for money.  You'll have to remember to round it for display *everywhere* you use it at, and you have potential accuracy issues if you divide or multiply by large numbers.  Decimal will give overflow errors, double will just lose accuracy.  I'm not sure about you, but with money, I'd prefer an error and aborted operation to silently proceeding with a loss of accuracy.

If anything, based on projects I've been on, you may want to consider using a struct that has a decimal and some indication of what currency it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. That is the reason I am using decimal right now. I am not planning to change it to double in the future, just be able to change it without having to refactor the entire application.

Answer (score 4):

Structs should be used for small types that will (in my opinion) be immutable, i.e., value types.  I am not sure what you mean by "used a lot", but if these structs will be passed around a lot in performance critical operations you will have to take into account the price of copying them versus the price of heap allocation.  I doubt you will need to take that into account, but it is something to think about.  I rarely find the need to use structs in my daily activities.

Also, as Jonathan points out, using the double type for money is a bad idea.  The decimal type is much better suited to financial calculations.

Yet another aside; you will probably hear a lot of responses which talk about stack v heap allocation, so this article may interest you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's kind of you to say.

Answer (score -1):

Structs may not be so accessible from .NET languages other than C#. Rounding errors could be a problem too. Why not just create a Money class and store the value as a Decimal and the currency used.

Comment: Do you mean a class as opposed to a struct?

Comment: I meant class. I've now updated my answer. Not sure why I got downvoted.